# Understanding/clarifying view controller syntax

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I've been looking at view controllers for a few days now (searching xcode help, google and stack overflow), and I think I have some understanding of it, but not a lot. 
I have some code, that I have trouble understanding.
So here I have the following code I found in the book I'm reading, and I'm not sure If I understand it correctly.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue(UIStoryboardsegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    ((ViewController2 *)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
}
```

First, I have no idea why we typecast to our second view controller(viewController2) here.
I think I get the rest though, we take the method's segue parameter (which holds information about the view controllers involved in the segue), and we access the destinationViewController(meaning that we want to access the view controller that we are going to). We then set the delegate property of the destination view controller to self. I believe we set the delegate property to self, because we want to send messages to a delegate in the view controller we're going to.

Heres the last one I don't get:

In the header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)id delegate;
```

In the implementation file: (the  controllerVisisble property is a boolean, and is changed to YES when the user hits a button to perform a manual segue to the second view controller, which is this one)

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    ((ViewController *)self.delegate).controllerrVisisble=NO;
}
```

Heres what I think this does: the viewWillDisappear method is called when a view is closing/removed.

I'm not quite sure about [super viewWillDisappear:animated], but I'm guessing that it gives an animation when the view disappears?However, I remove that line, and my dismissViewControllerAnimated method still gives an animation when the view controller is dismissed.

Here's the part that really confuses me. We need to access the first view controllers dateChooserVisible property somehow, to set it to NO, so we can access the second view controller again through our button. But, I don't understand why we have to typecast (viewController *), and type in self.delegate. Nor, do I understand why we created a property called delegate in the header file, to use here.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these questions are more generic than just within the context of view controllers.

- `[super methodName]` calls the superclasses implementation of the method named methodName.  In your case, Apple has written some code (that we don't have access to) in UIViewController's `viewWillDisappear:` method.  ALWAYS call super when overriding a method from a superclass.
- Note that `viewWillDisappear:` is just callback triggered whenever the view is set to disappear.  My guess is that the super implementation of this method forwards this callback down to child view controllers, especially in the case of standard container classes like `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`.
- The type casting really doesn't seem necessary, you can always call methods without compiler errors/warnings if the receiver is either type `id` or provides a declaration for the called method in its `@interface`.
- As far as the delegates go, protocols and delegation are a major part of Objective-C, and widely used in Apple's APIs.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) might help you understand how they work; it helped me immensely.

Comment: You do the cast because the compiler only knows that the destination controller is a generic view controller so you have to tell it is a specific custom class. Then you can assign the properties you need to pass data references between the controllers during the segue.

Comment: Good point, I missed that one, I only saw the `(ViewController *)self` bit.